# How do rates of change work?

Tags: calculus, functions

I know that if there is a function $f(x)$, its derivative with respect to $x$ is $\frac{df}{dx}$. However, I don't understand why $\frac{df}{dx}  \cdot dx = df$. I can see that the two $dx$ cancel, but I cannot get a feel for it. Please help me!

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: Mostafa Ayaz, thanks for your suggestion, I have now used MathJax to improve the readability of my question.

Comment: Writing $\frac{df}{dx} dx = df$ is usually just lazy notation for performing integration by substitution - it isn't actually a cancellation of fractions.

Comment: ConMan, I see that. But I don't get why multiplying the derivative of a function with respect to its input with a tiny change in the input gives the corresponding tiny change in the output of that function.